# Combining multi self in static functions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a static function. I want this function to be dynamic according to `$projectId`'s value. But how can I fix this code when I wanna do both when `$projectId` is not null. Thank you.

I want second self to be added to first one when `$projectId` is not null. When `$projectId` is null, I want only second self will be returned.

```
public static function getDetailed($projectId = null){
    if($projectId != null){
        Self::leftjoin('device_project', 'device_project.device_id', '=', 'devices.id')
        ->where('device_project.project_id', '=', $projectId);
    }
    return Self::select('devices.id AS device_id','devices.battery_level')
    ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like:

```
public static function getDetailed($projectId = null) {
    $device = Self::query();
   
    if ($projectId != null) {
        $device = Self::leftjoin('device_project', 'device_project.device_id', '=', 'devices.id')
                      ->where('device_project.project_id', '=', $projectId);
    }
    
    return $device->select('devices.id AS device_id','devices.battery_level')
                  ->get();
}
```

Comment: Yes I mean like this but `select` method should be later than `leftjoin` method. Because there will more columns in select method . After that other methods too. Is there a way for that?